# Issue with looping through elements in an inner array

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm having an issue looping through a set of css classes when an iteration of an outer loop is being executed.

What I'm trying to do is to append all the paragraphs under the current heading on to the new text that is being created, however, it only appears to append the first paragraph and then appends the second on to the hext heading.

What I would like is to have all content under each heading to be appended on each eg. para 1,2,3 appended under Heading 1, para 1 & 2 appended under Heading 2 etc.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Code is below and the script tag that's required is being created and the script runs without errors, I just need help on getting the correct paragraphs under heading to be joined correctly under each of the headings to form the correct text in the newly created script tag:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}

var els = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
for (var x = 0; x < els.length; x++) {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 481px)").matches) {
    els[x].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

//Question headers & Paragraph Answers

var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");

scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "application/ld+json");

var start = '{"@context": "https://schema.org","@type": "TestPage","mainEntity": [';
var end = ']}';
var headings = document.querySelectorAll(".list-test .accordion");
var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll(".panel > p");
var headElement = document.querySelector("header");

scriptTag.prepend(start);

for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < headings.length && j < paragraphs.length; i++, j++) {
  scriptTag.append('{"@type": "Question", "name": "' + headings[i].innerHTML + ' ", ');
  scriptTag.append('"acceptedAnswer": {"@type": "Answer","text": "' + paragraphs[j].innerHTML.trim() + ' "}}, ');
}

scriptTag.append(end);

headElement.append(scriptTag);
```

```css
.accordian-type {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: pink;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion.active,
p.accordion:hover {
  background: pink;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion:after {
  color: #fff;
}

@media all and (max-width: 40em) {
  .list-test {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <p>Test header</p>
</header>

<section class="row text-center list-test">
  <h2>
    Test List
  </h2>
  <p class="accordion accordian-type">List Header 1
  </p>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      <p>
        Para 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      </p>
      <p>
        Para 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      </p>
  </div>
  <p class="accordion accordian-type">List Header 2</p>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      <p>
        Para 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      </p>
  </div>
  <p class="accordion accordian-type">List Header 3</p>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      <p>
        Para 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      </p>
      <p>
        Para 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      </p>
      <p>
        Para 4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      </p>
  </div>
  <p class="accordion accordian-type">List Header 4</p>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      <p>
        Para 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      </p>
      <p>
        Para 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      </p>
      Para 4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    </p>
    <p>
      Para 5 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have reread the second and third paragraph of your question, but I don't understand what could be wrong with the behaviour and what you want different.

Comment: The first paragraph is being added to the List Heading 1 in the newly created json script block that's generated. However the second paragraph underneath the List Heading 1 is being appended to the List Heading 2 in the json block. What I need is for all the content under each of the headings to be added correctly in the newly created json script block, thanks

Comment: Yes, that is what I read in your question, but I don't understand it. Maybe someone else will...

Comment: Take for instance this part of the json: "Question", "name": "List Header 1
    ", "acceptedAnswer": {"@type": "Answer","text": "Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco "}} - the text section should include the other 2 paragraphs in the current list item eg. "text": "Para 1... Para 2... Para3 " , thanks for taking the time to look at this

Comment: In relation to this and the comments below, I was wondering if someone could assist/help out further to get the desired effect, thanks